# Shutdown windows after build visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, shutdown

I would like to let my computer build big projects over night (like Unreal Engine)
but i don't want my computer to be on all night. Now making a shutdown timer is really not reliable, so i wondered if there was a way to shutdown windows after my C++ build in visual studio is complete.

Thanks in advance!
Greets,
Joejoepie

Comment: You could invoke `shutdown` in the post-build event actions.

Comment: Thank you. This would indeed work for normal projects, but i found out that in a project like Unreal Engine you can't edit the post-build events. However for every other project this is an excelent solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do the build *in* Visual Studio.

Write a batch file that (1) invokes `msbuild` or `devenv`, and (2) invokes `shutdown`.

Comment: Seems like a great idea, i will look into that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Set auto shutdown via Run.**

If you have an idea of how long the project build will take (just over-estimate a guess), this method could solve your issue:

> Open Run by Windows+R, type shutdown –s –t number and tap OK.

The number in the run command represents the value of seconds. For example, if you want your PC to automatically shut down in 10 minutes, the command to be entered is shutdown –s –t 600. After finishing this setting, the system will prompt you with the auto shutdown time.

*You can also accomplish this via Command Prompt or Windows Powershell:

> Type shutdown –s –t 1200 (i.e. 20 minutes) and press Enter.

**Use the Task Scheduler tool (built in with Windows).**

This tool provides the option to shutdown when a specific event is logged if you would prefer not to guess at how long the build will take.

> "Create a basic task" > type "Shutdown" as the task name (click Next)  > Choose when the task starts (One time), you can also choose "when a specific event is logged" (click Next) > Set the start time of the task (click Next) > Select Start a program (click Next) > Click the Browse button, open Disk `C/Windows/System32`, choose the `.exe` file named "shutdown" (click Open) > Enter –s as the argument (click Next) > Click Finish to complete the task creation and bring the task into effect.

Comment: This would be my last resort, because it is unreliable, like i stated in my question. Nevertheless thank you for your detailed answer!